# Mail app correctly marks spam but does not move it to the junk mail folder

Tags: mail.app, imap, spam

as by message, Mail app does not bother moving mail correctly marked as spam in the spam folder -- this only happen when I am at home, and only during the week-end.  I suspect that the IMAP server is to be blamed.  I could try to delete the account and recreate it, but since it's my work email, and the server is showing some problems, I am quite lukewarm about this solution ([Mail app problem in Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34764/mail-app-shows-junk-mails-in-my-inbox)).  Is there another less drastic way of solving the problem?

I'm on OS 10.8.3 all latest whistles and bells.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need open the preferences window (command + ,)
2. Click on Junk Mail pane
3. Select: "Move it to the Junk mailbox (Automatic)"